# What does the phrase "keep it locked it in" mean?

Tags: meaning

Here is the context:

> As always **keep it locked in** here on my videos and I will see you in the next one.

Does it just mean watch my videos? If it does, then where does this phrase originate from?

Comment: To help us answer this question, can you please give us more context. A link to the source would be ideal, but it would also help to know what 'it' refers to. FYI, 'keep locked in' is sometimes heard on some radio stations, meaning 'keep tuned to this station'. It is quite likely that some on-line blogs or sites are using the same phrase, probably meaning 'keep coming back here for more (whatever they provide)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we don't have sufficient context we must guess.  This guess could be right or it could be very wrong.

If this is a hipster-cool "tag line", like the slogans used by popular radio station DJs of yesteryear as they signed off from their shows, **keep it locked in here** would mean:

*stay tuned to this station*.

There, **it** would not be anaphoric but existential/elliptical, referring to your tuning dial.

That is, don't change to some other station (or channel, *mutatis mutandis*).

And **I will see you in the next one** could mean "I will see you in the next life."   DJs can be "space-cadettes" who say some "far out" things.

Or it could mean "I will see you in the next set of videos".